# Regular expressions with \b and non-word characters (like '.')

Tags: python, regex

Why does this regular expression:
`r'^(?P<first_init>\b\w\.\b)\s(?P<mid_init>\b\w\.\b)\s(?P<last_name>\b\w+\b)$'`
does not match `J. F. Kennedy`?

I  have to remove `\b` in groups `first_init` and `mid_init` to match the words.
I am using Python. And for testing i am using https://regex101.com/

Thanks

Comment: Does `r"\b\w\.\b"` by itself  match anything in "J. F. Kennedy"?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. Thanks. 
No it does not. But why  'J.'  does not match "word boundary -> followed by a character -> followed by a '.' ". Thats what the regex is asking to match. Right?

Comment: It  is all in the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, look at \b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-applying the `\b` *word breaks*.

`\b` will *only* match if on one side there is a valid "word" character and on the other side not. Now you use this construction twice:

```
\b\w\.\b\s
```

.. and, rightly so, it does not match because on the left side you have a not-word character (a single full stop) and on the other side you *also* have a not-word character (a space).

Removing the `\b` between the full stop and `\s` is enough to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @Rad Lexus. Your explanation was very clear. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` matches the empty string only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters. The dot (`.`) cannot comprise part of the word.

```
>>> import re
# does not match when \. is within word boundary
>>> re.match(r'^(?P<first_init>\b\w\.\b)\s(?P<mid_init>\b\w\.\b)\s(?P<last_name>\b\w+\b)$', 'J. F. Kennedy')
# matches when \b is moved to left of \.
>>> re.match(r'^(?P<first_init>\b\w\b\.)\s(?P<mid_init>\b\w\b\.)\s(?P<last_name>\b\w+\b)$', 'J. F. Kennedy')  # matches
```

The `.` is not part of the word in this sense. See the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the second boundary:

```
^(?P<first_init>\b\w\.)\s
(?P<mid_init>\b\w\.)\s
(?P<last_name>\b\w+\b)$
```

And see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xM7cA5/2).
*Background* is that the second `\b` is between a dot and a space, so it fails (remember that one of the sides needs to be a word character, ie one of `a-zA-Z0-9_`)

Comment: Thanks for the demo :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not match because of the `\.` (dot) character. A word boundary does not include the dot (it is not the same definition of *word* you perhaps would like). You can easily rewrite it without the need of `\b`. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) carefully.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

\b means border of a word.

`Word` here is defined like so:

> A word ends, when there is a space character following it.

"J.", "F." and "Kennedy" are the words here.

You're example is trying to search for a space between the letter and the dot and it is searching for `J . F . Kennedy`.